# Generador de código aleatorio que no se repita

Tags: php, funciones

¿Cómo puedo hacer un generador de códigos con letras y números que no se repita? 
La intención es almacenar este código único a cada usuario al darle al botón de submit de un formulario, no importa si antes de ello tengo que darle a otro botón para generar el código y luego pasarlo a form con el sumbit.

**Nota:** este código es un submit muy sencillo de 8 datos que se almacenan en un base de datos.

```html
<div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title">Agregar </h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">     
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre"  id="nombre" class="form-control" required>
        
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Cédula</label>
        <input type="text" name="cedula" id="cedula" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Correo electrónico:</label>
        <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>teléfono:</label>
        <input type="telefono" name="telefono" id="telefono" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Celular:</label>
        <input type="text" name="celular" id="celular" class="form-control" required>
    </div>     
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Número de placa:</label>
        <input type="text" name="placa" id="placa" class="form-control" required>
    </div>  

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Guardar datos">
</div>
```

botón  guardar

Comment: has intentado crear un GUID o una función como uniqid(); ?

Comment: Tiene que tener números obligatoriamente? sino podes jugar un poco con fechas

Comment: nose es que serian muchos usuarios como 10 mil algo asi entonces un alfanumerico me parece mejor nose?

Comment: Prueba [PHP hash](http://php.net/manual/es/function.hash.php#refsect1-function.hash-seealso) y las demás funciones que generan un valor cifrado.

Answer (score 2):

puedes utilizar esta sencilla función:

```
function generarCodigo($longitud) {
    $key = '';
    $pattern = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $max = strlen($pattern)-1;
    for($i=0;$i < $longitud;$i++) $key .= $pattern{mt_rand(0,$max)};
    return $key;
}
```

//Ejemplo de uso

```
echo generarCodigo(6); // genera un código de 6 caracteres de longitud.
```

*Fuente: http://www.inkuba.com/blog/generar-codigo-aleatorio-con-php/*

Answer (score 1):

Podrías tratar el email como un campo **UNIQUE** en tu base de datos, con el fin de garantizar que no se pueda repetir y que te sirva más o menos como una clave primaria.

Luego podrías encriptar este email en **md5**, en PHP existe una función específica para esto:

**PHP**

```
$email = "miEmailUnico@gmail.com";
echo md5($email);
```

Y luego ya guardarlo donde más te interese.

Si en tu DB almacenas a tus usuarios con un campo autoincremental como clave primaria, podrías usar ese mismo número codificado en **md5** para conseguir el mismo resultado.

Sin saber lo que pretendes hacer con ese código aleatorio no podría decirte cual de las opciones te podría venir mejor.

**EDIT**

```
function genera_codigo ($longitud) {
    $caracteres = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
    $codigo = '';

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $longitud; $i++) {
        $codigo .= $caracteres[numero_aleatorio(0, 35)];
    }

    return $codigo;
}

function numero_aleatorio ($ninicial, $nfinal) {
    $numero = rand($ninicial, $nfinal);

    return $numero;
}

echo genera_codigo(5);
```

Esta podría ser un sencillo programa para generar un número aleatorio alfanumérico, pudiendo elegir la longitud del código a generar. Lo único que tendrías que hacer es antes de insertarlo en la DB comprobar si existe e insertarlo o pedir otro dependiendo de la respuesta.

Existen mil maneras de hacer un programa similar, es lo primero que se me ha ocurrido y que además me parece bastante sencillo de entender.

Comment: seria como para realizar consultas de información del usuario al yo ingresar el código de el usuario en un textbox este me muestre la información del usuario correo, nombre, celular.. etc

Comment: podria solo consultar con el id ya que en la base el id es llave primaria y auto increment pero me gustaría que sea un código y no un numero:

Comment: Cualquier de las 2 opciones que te comento te podría valer para eso. Si tienes almacenados a los usuarios con una PK autoincremental yo no lo duraría y usaría ese campo para hacer la encriptación md5. Sabes que es algo que no se va a repetir en otro usuario.

Comment: Lo que te propongo podría valerte, te genera un código bastante "inflado" en hexadecimal. De tal manera que al usuario con la ID 1 se le asignaría algo como:  c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b

Comment: es que es muy largo y también me gustaría que el usuario tuviera su código y hacerlo así es muy largo me gustaría que tenga un rango de 5 caracteres entre letras y números para almacenarlo junto al formulario con los datos de cada usuario

Comment: La gracia del método que te exponía era que no necesitabas comprobar después en la base de datos si existía un código igual, sabrías que el que insertaras iba a ser único, evitándote ese paso. Si necesitas algo más corto ya se tendría que diseñar una función de caracteres aleatorios y antes de insertar el resultado de esa función, comprobar primero si no existe en la DB y en caso correcto ya insertarlo.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para añadir un sencillo programa que te devuelve un código alfanumérico aleatorio de la longitud que le pases como parámetro.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar la función UNIQID() de php, 
te será mucho más sencillo y rapdido,
aquí te dejo la documentación y algunos ejemplos basicos.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.uniqid.php

//codigo aleatorio de 13 cifras

echo uniqid();

//codigo aleatorio de 13 cifras concatenado con string

echo uniqid('cod_');

//codigo aleatorio de 23 cifras concatenado con string

echo uniqid('num_', true);

Answer (score -1):

y que este codigo no se repita,

```html
<?php



function generarCodigos($cantidad=3, $longitud=10, $incluyeNum=true){ 
    $caracteres = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
    if($incluyeNum) 
        $caracteres .= "1234567890"; 
     
    $arrPassResult=array(); 
    $index=0; 
    while($index<$cantidad){ 
        $tmp=""; 
        for($i=0;$i<$longitud;$i++){ 
            $tmp.=$caracteres[rand(0,strlen($caracteres)-1)]; 
        } 
        if(!in_array($tmp, $arrPassResult)){ 
            $arrPassResult[]=$tmp; 
            $index++; 
        } 
    } 
    return $tmp; 
}  
$codigos=generarCodigos(1,5); 
print_r($codigos);
```

podría ser algo como esto?

Answer (score -1):

como puedo hacer que al presionar el botón "generar" me muestre el valor de la función en un text sin

```html
<?php



function generarCodigos($cantidad=3, $longitud=10, $incluyeNum=true){ 
    $caracteres = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
    if($incluyeNum) 
        $caracteres .= "1234567890"; 
     
    $arrPassResult=array(); 
    $index=0; 
    while($index<$cantidad){ 
        $tmp=""; 
        for($i=0;$i<$longitud;$i++){ 
            $tmp.=$caracteres[rand(0,strlen($caracteres)-1)]; 
        } 
        if(!in_array($tmp, $arrPassResult)){ 
            $arrPassResult[]=$tmp; 
            $index++; 
        } 
    } 
    return $tmp; 
}  
$codigos=generarCodigos(1,5); 
 


?>





<html>
<input type="text" name="code" value="">

<input type="button" id="generar" name="generar" value="generar codigo" onclick="">
</html>
```

submit?

Comment: esta es una pregunta o respuesta a la publicación? @JEFF meza?